# Dynamically Customize JSON Returned From A Spring Boot REST Service Using Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I am developing a REST service using Spring Boot and Jackson.  For this service the caller can specify the list of fields they want in the result.  Suppose we had this java class for which we return the fields to the user:

```
public class Customer {
    
    public int id;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String addressLine1;
    public String addressLine2;
    public String city;
    public String state;
    public String zip;
    public String phone;

}
```

The client would call our service:

https://myhost.net/getCustomer?id=2112&lof=id,firstName,lastName

Where the **lof** parameter is the "list of fields" that the client wants.

This is obviously a simple example, we are implementing something much larger and many more fields are being returned.  In addition we are returning many occurrences of objects in 1 call.  The requirement is that the client can limit the fields to only the fields they are interested in.

Annotations are out of the question for obvious reasons.

How can I control how the objects are serialized on a per request basis?

Thanks much!
Paul

Comment: Where are you getting these values from? How are you setting them? Have you looked at reflection/bean mappers?

Comment: Well, you can always create a map, put only the properties needed into that map and serialize it.

Comment: This is very good requirement for GraphQL if you want to check https://www.baeldung.com/spring-graphql

Comment: @Thomas I hadn't considered that option.  Sometimes the simple answers are just genius!

Comment: @Thomas again thanks.  45 minutes later and I have this implemented and working.  Now for a little clean up and on to the next feature!

Answer (score 0):

What you could do:

- Register a serialize that will take this field list in consideration https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization
- Create a wrapper (or proxy) that will return null for fields that should not be fetched and use `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` annotation, but there you loose the distinction between not present and null field

Comment: Appreciate the response.  I was actually looking at this very same Baeldung page when I saw your response.  It seemed promising at first.  My problem is where I know the list of fields (lof) and where/when the serializer is constructed - it not simple to get that information to the serializer.  If that makes any sense... Again thanks!

Comment: U can have a wrapper that holds that information, and this is then used by serializer. something like T would be a concrete Dto `LofWrapper<T >{  @JsonUnwrapped T concreteDto; List<String> listOfFields}` also Yeah consider graphQl - the first thing you learn when reading or watching anything about REST is that REST is not always the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it using dynamic @JsonView, but, as it was mentioned in one of the comments, graphql is the way to go.